# Entity relationship in DropdownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Currently I have the following entities:

Movie:

```
public class Movie
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency), Range(1,100)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Rating { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string comments { get; set; }


    public Director director { get; set; }
}
```

Director:

```
[Table("Director")]
public class Director
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    [Required, Range(1,100)]
    public int age { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string fullName {
        get { return this.name + " " + this.lastName; }
    }
}
```

When I access the edit form, I load a SelectList from the Directors in the DB:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
        if (movie == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.Directors = new SelectList(db.Directors.ToList(), "ID", "fullname");
        return View(movie);
    }
```

Then I use @Html.DropDownListFor to show the combo box in the form:

```
 <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.director, (SelectList)ViewBag.Directors, "Select")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.director)
    </div>
```

Everything seems to be alright, but when I select an option and try to save the form, I get a validation message saying that  "The value '1' is invalid". Where '1' is the Director ID.

So, definitely I'm missing something to directly bind the Director.

Comment: Your dropdown list is a list of IDs, your director property is of type `Director`. You should have a `DirectorID` property somewhere in that `Movie` class.

Comment: Isn't there a way to accomplish the same without adding a DirectorID?

Comment: Your going to have to build a custom Model Binder for that to work. Or a better way is to create a ViewModel specifically for the form, containing a DirectorId property.

Comment: PLease show the controller action, the httpPost one

Comment: I'll check the custom Model Binder.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't whant to modify ID by convention, than you may change a bit your code, which creates SelectList:

```
var list = new List<SelectListItem>;

var items = from n in db.Directors
            select new SelectListItem
            {
              Text = n.fullname,
              Value = n.ID
             };
//*Add your items to List
foreach (var item in items)
    list.Add(item);

ViewBag.Directors = list;
```

**EDITED:** 
Don't look at my first part. Commentators were right. Your models are not connected. You need `directorID` property in your `Movie` model to make it work. Than you should change your `DropDownListFor` as folows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.directorID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Directors, "Select")
```

Comment: How is that different than what he posted? Does the same thing IMO.

Comment: @mxmissile You are right. Thank you. I didn't understand question in right way.

Comment: Allright, what I'm trying to avoid is to add that property directorID to my Movie Model.

Comment: @federico.luppi dont add it to your Move model. You create a new "form model" that contains DirectorID. Then update your Movie model from the form model. I actually prefer specialized models for my views and forms rather than sending my db populated domain models down the wire. Then I dont have to decorate my domain models with all this view validation crap among other benefits.

Comment: @mxmissile It will work for saving data. But how we'll get back Movie's director if Movie database table doesn't contain directorID field? May be I didn't properly undertand your comment.

Comment: @Andrey.Gubal When I declare the Director property in Movie entity, it modifies the table definition and includes the DirectorID column in Movie Table.

Answer (score 0):

Is your entity auto generated, or you made it your self.
If you have auto generated, it doesn't seem like you have relationship between Director and Movie. Else your movie would have property DirectorID, and Directory entity would have ICollection of Movies.
Further while using DropDownlistFor in movies for Director you should you DirectorID and that would be the correct way to do it.
i.e.

```
public class Movie
{

public int ID { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Title { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Genre { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.Currency), Range(1,100)]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
[StringLength(5)]
public string Rating { get; set; }
[StringLength(200)]
public string comments { get; set; }
//change here
public int DirectorID {get; set;}

public Director director { get; set; }
}
```

And select list would be

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DirectorID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Directors, "Select")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DirectorID)
</div>
```

And to populate the directors you can create a select list by

```
var directors=db.Directors.Select(o=>new {ID=o.DirectorID, Name=o.DirectorName});
```

And the Add this select list to viewbag as usual.

```
ViewBag.Directors = new SelectList(directors, "ID", "Name");
```

Comment: With this solution, the Director property doesn't populate when I load the Movie. So I can't do something like movie.director.name